# How to set WebLogic JVM argument on multiple servers

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, jvm-arguments

I want to set a JVM argument to some WebLogic managed servers. 
This arguments are same on all servers. (-Dconfserver=11.1.1.1:6666)

I know how to set it on a single server (in console "server start" tab), but there's 10+ managed servers and they are on different machines. I don't want to repeat the console operation or edit the start shell script for 10+ times . Is there any better way to set this for all managed servers?

WebLogic version is 10.3.6 (11gR1)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to access each server individually.

you can shutdown the admin server.

then edit the `config.xml` file in the **Admin Server** only.

And add this `argument` to each `<server-start>` in that file.

then start the Admin Server, and restart the servers and they will get the new configurations.

Comment: Actually what I want is how to "select multiple argurment targets". It  seems there is no way to do that. but your answer is good:) To copy <server-start> 10times is still quicker than setting each server in weblogic console. Thanks.